# How can I fix KeyError when using requires in web2py Table Field definition with reference type?

Tags: web2py

I've been trying to set the requires property in a table in a web2py application I've taken over so that the validator will limit the values for the drop-down in the form to a subset of the user accounts. I've read a couple of posts on Google forums, eg https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/web2py/n2c3xP6EQ8I, and here suggesting it can be done and I've followed those such that I now have the following field definition in the table:

```
Field('supervisor', type='reference auth_user', label=T('Supervisor'), requires=IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_IN_DB(db((db.auth_user.is_active == True) & (db.auth_user.id == db.auth_membership.user_id) & (db.auth_membership.group_id != 5)), db.auth_user.id, db.auth_user._format))),
```

When I run the application though I get an error that says:

```
<class 'KeyError'> 'id'
```

I have tried other suggestions like adding:

```
represent=lambda id, r: '%(first_name)s %(last_name)s' % db.auth_user(id)
```

to the Field definition but it comes up with the same error.

I've tried breaking the query into two and using the **_and** option with IS_NOT_IN_DB since it seemed this might give a similar effect:

```
Field('supervisor', type='reference auth_user', label=T('Supervisor'), requires=IS_EMPTY_OR(IS_IN_DB(db(db.auth_user.is_active == True), db.auth_user.id, db.auth_user._format, _and=IS_NOT_IN_DB(db(db.auth_membership.group_id != 5), db.auth_membership.user_id)))),
```

Whilst the above doesn't generate an error it also doesn't exclude the unwanted users in the drop-down correctly either. The only thought I had here was that it might be because the the application is using crud to generate the forms instead of explicitly using SQLFORM and a post I saw mentioned that Crud has essentially been dropped in favour of SQLFORM...

For reference my web2py version is 2.17.2 downloaded from source.

Does anyone know how I might fix the field definition to make this work?

**UPDATED (2018/11/200):**

Sorry, here's the traceback:

**Traceback**

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Ben\python\web2py\gluon\restricted.py", line 219, in restricted
    exec(ccode, environment)
File "C:/Users/Ben/python/web2py/applications/lycomms/controllers/work_order.py", line 412, in <module>
File "C:\Users\Ben\python\web2py\gluon\globals.py", line 421, in <lambda>
    self._caller = lambda f: f()
File "C:\Users\Ben\python\web2py\gluon\tools.py", line 3867, in f
    return action(*a, **b)
File "C:/Users/Ben/python/web2py/applications/lycomms/controllers/work_order.py", line 187, in add
    form = crud.create(db.work_order)
File "C:\Users\Ben\python\web2py\gluon\tools.py", line 4374, in create
    **attributes
File "C:\Users\Ben\python\web2py\gluon\tools.py", line 4296, in update
    **attributes  # contains hidden
File "C:\Users\Ben\python\web2py\gluon\sqlhtml.py", line 1523, in __init__
    inp = self.widgets.options.widget(field, default)
File "C:\Users\Ben\python\web2py\gluon\sqlhtml.py", line 325, in widget
    options = requires[0].options()
File "C:\Users\Ben\python\web2py\gluon\validators.py", line 2795, in _options
    options = self.other.options(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Ben\python\web2py\gluon\validators.py", line 601, in options
    self.build_set()
File "C:\Users\Ben\python\web2py\gluon\validators.py", line 594, in build_set
    self.theset = [str(r[self.kfield]) for r in records]
File "C:\Users\Ben\python\web2py\gluon\validators.py", line 594, in <listcomp>
    self.theset = [str(r[self.kfield]) for r in records]
File "C:\Users\Ben\python\web2py\gluon\packages\dal\pydal\objects.py", line 94, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'id'
```

**Function Argument List**

```
(self=<Row {'auth_user': {'id': 39, 'first_name': 'Ben...ship': {'id': 83, 'user_id': 39, 'group_id': 2}}>, k='id')
```

Comment: Always provide the full traceback.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Anthony. I've updated the question with the traceback and I included the Function Argument List part as well in case it helps.

Comment: Actually, using the exact code you provided in the first line above, I cannot reproduce the error. I suggest you post on the Google Group and maybe attach a minimal app that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help Anthony I appreciate it. The app is pretty old so there could be something else there that's breaking it. A simpler reference works without a problem though so for now I'll just add another column to auth_user as a work around and come back to it later.